# Doctrine2 dbal cache subquery

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

I have a very expensive subquery that I use for multiple queries in my repository.

I want to find a way to cache that subquery and use it's results in the other native sql queries.

1. I am using the Doctrine2 DBAL in a symfony2 project.
2. Native SQL is required due to the complexity of the subquery.

```
example:

select sum(volume) from ( expensive_subquery );
```

I have been reviewing Google, and the Doctrine2 documentation but have not found a good solution here.

Other methods are welcome, staying in the confines of the Doctrine2, Symfony2, SQL framework.

Comment: After looking around a bit, and thinking about it some more, I think, saveing some kind of ability to cache the sub-query, the best way may be to create a temporary table in memory from the sub-query, and run the other queries against that. This is what I'm going to try for the time being, however, cacheing would be cleaner i'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options. My first line of action would be to hash the select statement to act as a key and store the results in memcached or something similar. Then in your manager before your run the query. Check to see if the key/cache exists.. If it does,use the cached results.. If the cache didn't exist, create it after the long query runs.. Additionally, you might want to integrate cache expiration.